# Inequality with 5 cyclic variables

Tags: inequality, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, tangent-line-method

For postive real numbers $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ and $e$, prove that

$$\frac{4a^3}{a^2+2b^2+\frac{2b^3}{a}} + \frac{4b^3}{b^2+2c^2+\frac{2c^3}{b}} + \frac{4c^3}{c^2+2d^2+\frac{2d^3}{c}}+ \frac{4d^3}{d^2+2e^2+\frac{2e^3}{d}} + \frac{4e^3}{e^2+2a^2+\frac{2a^3}{e}}  \geq $$ $$ \frac{2ab^2+2b^3}{a^2+2b^2 + 2\frac{b^3}{a} } + \frac{2bc^2+2c^3}{b^2+2c^2 + 2\frac{c^3}{b} }+ \frac{2cd^2+2d^3}{c^2+2d^2 + 2\frac{d^3}{c} } + \frac{2de^2+2e^3}{d^2+2e^2 + 2\frac{e^3}{d} } + \frac{2ea^2+2a^3}{e^2+2a^2 + 2\frac{a^3}{e} }$$

Can this be solved directly by $ AM-GM $?

Comment: @Esposa Do Yoongi I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Unfortunately I could do nothing but try to apply some inequalities of averages. I also did some unknown substitution in the denominator to see if it would help, replace all with one. Obviously it didn't work, it got tangled, in the numerator maybe it would be simpler

Comment: But this results in an irreducible

Comment: take everything left and factor. You will have to for example 4a³ - 2ab² - 2b³ = 2a³ - 2b³ + 2a³ - 2ab² 2 [a³ - b³ + a (a² - b²)] = 2 [(a - b) (a² + ab + b²) + a ( a - b) (a + b)] = 2 (a - b) (a² + ab + b² + a² + ab) = 2 (a - b) ((a + b) ² + a²)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a^3}{a^2+2b^2+\frac{2b^3}{a}}-\sum_{cyc}\frac{2ab^2+2b^3}{a^2+2b^2+\frac{2b^3}{a}}=2\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a^4-a^2b^2-ab^3}{a^3+2ab^2+2b^3}=$$
$$=2\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2a^4-a^2b^2-ab^3}{a^3+2ab^2+2b^3}-(a-b)\right)=2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4+a^3b-3a^2b^2-ab^3+2b^4}{a^3+2ab^2+2b^3}=$$
$$=2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4-3a^2b^2+2ab^3+a^3b-3ab^3+2b^4}{a^3+2ab^2+2b^3}=2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a^3-3ab^2+2b^3)}{a^3+2ab^2+2b^3}\geq$$
$$\geq2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)\left(3\sqrt[3]{a^3\cdot\left(b^3\right)^2}-3ab^2\right)}{a^3+2ab^2+2b^3}=0.$$